# How to auto start instance of sql server 2012 localdb on startup?

Tags: sql-server, windows

How do you auto start instance of sql server 2012 localdb on startup?

Comment: Install SQL Server 2012 non-LocalDB.

Comment: A powershell or batch file that runs on startup with `SqlLocalDB create MyInstance -s` will do it

Answer (score 1):

Create a Windows Service program that uses the instance.  Auto start your program.

Or, use SQL Server Express, which is also free, and can be setup to run at startup - this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You shall not forget that there is too this legacy Startup folder under 'All Programs' menu that can be used to launch programs at log on. Henceforth, simply create a .cmd file with the following content (or alike, to be adjusted to your DB instance name and path):

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" start MyDBInstance
```

and then copy this file inside this folder (to be possibly adjusted to your windows path, requires local admin rights):

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
```

from where it will be executed each time a user logs on